# My local ubuntu server is not updated

Tags: mirrors

I am from Nepal and it's faster to download apps from server for nepal using through ubuntu software center. But when i use np.archive.ubuntu.com server. There is no updated softwares and few softwares and nvidia driver are outdated. for e.g. i cannot even install openshot when i user server for nepal. It provides error which cannot be solved.

I want to know how can the server for nepal be updated frequently with us.archive.ubuntu.com. i use ubuntu 12.10. and i want to use server for nepal since the download speed faster than 2x than from us server.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue too as I belong to Nepal as well. However, the following link shows that the server for Nepal which is supposed to provide download up to 100kbps is currently not updated... search for Nepal's server section in the address and see the details there.... so it's better we choose another mirror.. maybe of Indonessia or other until the server gets updated..

Requesting server update procedure may be by informing the owner of the server i.e. Kshitiz Shrestha that the server is outdated...

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu.ntc.net.np-archive

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

**Update:**

Bro, the server is updated now... you can use Nepal's server now... enjoy downloads..:)

Happy Linuxing

Comment: The mirror archive for ubuntu in nepal is now up to date. You can change your software source to ubuntu.ntc.net.np. For help, refer to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/np.archive.ubuntu.com-archive

Answer (score -1):

Isn't 12.10 the most recent version, or do you mean the *program* updates?

If that's the case, then [this may help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1201354).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks. I was posing it as an _if_, though, because I'm not sure if that's the answer they're looking for, in particular.