# Error 404 when trying to install the package linux-image-extra

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center

I am trying to install the package below on ubuntu/trusty64

```
apt-get install -y linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

and getting the following error

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic amd64 3.13.0-46.75
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic_3.13.0-46.75_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
```

When I go to the url above I see the relevant file but with 77 in the file name instead of 75.
`http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic_3.13.0-46.77_amd64.deb`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 2):

Your sources might not be up to date.

`sudo apt-get update`

or the mirror you are using might be out of date as referenced in [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206726/my-local-ubuntu-server-is-not-updated)